# gvim syntastic Error: Module XXX cannot read file 'file\etc\etc'

Tags: vim, d, syntastic

I have a set of libraries that live in another folder and syntastic is trying to look for this libraries in the same folder where program lives.  For example, the program I have, let's call it, `myprogr.d` is in `c:\programming\myprogr.d`.  There are libraries inside that program that are address as this

```
private import jic.libs.myLibs;
```

and this library exists in `C:\D\Import\jic\libs\mylibs.d`.  When I compile this program, I pass `-IC:\D\Import` option to the compiler whom finds the entry point for the mentioned library and continues one without a problem.  How can I make Syntastic not give me this error?

Comment: What are the permissions on the files?

Comment: what is the name of the module in the file mylibs.d ?

Comment: You're importing `myLibs` (capital L) but the filename (and probably the module name) is `mylibs` (lowercase L). By convention, module names in D should be all lowercase.